# How do I align the image and the text in this li and span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an image and text in an li and span.
I've tried a lot of questions and answers similar to this, but no success.
Using a label or table is not an option unfortunately.

Thanks

[image]

```css
.checkbox, .radio {
 width: 19px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url(../../Content/Images/TriStateCheckboxes.jpg);
 display: block;
 clear: left;
 float: left;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
    background: url(../../Content/Images/PermissionChecked.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: -20px;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: -20px;
}

li 
{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM0" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
<li>
    <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_0">
        <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_MM_0">
            <input name="MM_0" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="MM_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="FkComponentId= ComponentId=2 Granted=-1 PermissionId=0|">
        </span>
        <span>
          LookupTables
        </span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </span>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse show" id="MMID_0" style="padding-left: 60px;"> 
    <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_00">
            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_SM_0_0">
               <input name="SM_0_0" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false">
            </span>
            <span>
              Countries
            </span>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please show some demo how you want tit to look??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex;` in your container, and then `align-items: center` to center them.
Also, to remove the order image use `list-style-type: none;`

```css
.checkbox,
.radio {
  width: 19px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(../../Content/Images/TriStateCheckboxes.jpg);
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-heading {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM00">
  <li>
    <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_0 ">
      <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_MM_0 ">
        <input name="MM_0" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="MM_0" style="display: none; " type="checkbox" value="false" >
      </span>
    <span>
        LookupTables
      </span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, however my li-items are now vertically spaced very far apart.

Comment: Solved, thanks, set the height in the accordion heading container

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` to `.red` and position with `top/left` as you want...

Also use `position:relative` to wrap DOM in your case `.accordion-heading`

```css
    .checkbox,
    .radio {
      width: 19px;
      height: 20px;
      padding: 0px;
      background: url(../../Content/Images/TriStateCheckboxes.jpg);
      display: block;
      clear: left;
      float: left;
    }

    .accordion-heading {
      position: relative;
    }

    .red {
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      left: -28px;
    }

    li {
      cursor: pointer;
list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM00" style="b order-image; none;">

  <li>
    <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#MMID_0 ">
                <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red " id="sp_MM_0 ">
                    <input name="MM_0 " class="MMTree-checkbox styled red " id="MM_0 " style="display: none; " type="checkbox " value="false " ></span>
    <span>
                       LookupTables
                    </span>
    <span class="caret "></span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This comes close thanks, see my edits and the image. It's just the top image that is missing now.

Comment: Setting the accordionheading causes both first and second image to disappear

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to use `flex`, you can use combo `absolute` + `transform: translate` :D. So in my code,

```
position: absolute; top: 50%;
```

mean 50% of 1st parent with `position: reative` (`li>span`)

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

mean 50% of itself

```css
.checkbox, .radio {
 width: 19px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: url(../../Content/Images/TriStateCheckboxes.jpg);
 display: block;
}
.red 
{
    background-color: red;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
li>span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li>span span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
li>span span:last-child{
    left: unset;
    right: 0px;
}
li>span span:nth-child(2){
    right: unset;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM0" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
<li>
<span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_0">
    <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_MM_0">
        <input name="MM_0" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="MM_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="FkComponentId= ComponentId=2 Granted=-1 PermissionId=0|">
    </span>
    <span>
      LookupTables
    </span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</span>
<br/>
<ul class="nav nav-list collapse show" id="MMID_0" style="padding-left: 60px;"> 
<li>
    <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_00">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_SM_0_0">
           <input name="SM_0_0" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false">
        </span>
        <span>
          Countries
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_00">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red" id="sp_SM_0_0">
           <input name="SM_0_0" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false">
        </span>
        <span>
          Age
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, very close to what I want, only the top li is incorrect.

Comment: Because `display` prop of `li>span` is `inline` (default of text), it mean you cannot change height or width like `display: block`. So set `display: inline-block` to have twice feature props. Checkout my edited code, hope this is useful.